# Error on loading CSV using fread in pydatatable

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have a csv contains about 600K observations, and I'm importing it using fread

```
DT = dt.fread('C:\\Users\\myamulla\\Desktop\\proyectos_de_py\\7726_analysis\\datasets\\7726export_Jan_23.csv')
```

It is throwing out an error as -

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-01684fbecd91> in <module>
----> 1 dt.fread('C:\\Users\\myamulla\\Desktop\\proyectos_de_py\\7726_analysis\\datasets\\7726export_Jan_23.csv')

IOError: Too few fields on line 432815: expected 14 but found only 4 (with sep=','). Set fill=True to ignore this error.  <<19731764,2021-01-23 23:30:15,2021-01-23 23:42:20,"Vote for David Borrero, your Republican in HD 105. Potestad betrayed Prez Trump. Borrero is for our values & POTUS Trump.>>
```

As suggested here, i passed the argument fill=True in fread statement.

```
DT = dt.fread('C:\\Users\\myamulla\\Desktop\\proyectos_de_py\\7726_analysis\\datasets\\7726export_Jan_23.csv',fill=True)
```

It executes, but DT will be created EMPTY.

How to get it resolved ?

Comment: My suggestion would be to Try reading it with another library and see if you get the same issue. If not, then I would suggest raising an issue on the GitHub page. Try it with pandas or any other library and see if the error persists.

Comment: The same file gets imported successfully in pandas.

Comment: A GitHub issue is in order then